# Angular v2+ typescript deep copy/clone with getters

Tags: angular, typescript, deep-copy

How can I copy/clone a typescript class? The parent class contains a nested class and also a collection of the nested class. Each type of class contains a getter.
I would like if the copied class did not lose the getters, and the nested class and the array items have a new reference.

My problems are, the `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify( obj ));` not copied the getters. and the `Object.assign(target, soure);` copied the getters, but the array items keep the original references.

Here is the structure of classes

```
export interface IClassA {
  code: number;
  description: string;
}

export class ClassA implements IClassA {
  code: number;
  description: string;
  get descrAndCode() {
    return 'Getter A ' + this.description + ':' + this.code;
  }
}

export interface IClassB {
  name: string;
  code: number;
  classList: Array<ClassA>;
}

export class ClassB implements IClassB {
  name: string;
  code: number;
  get codeAndName(): string {
    return 'Getter B' + this.code + ':' + this.name;
  }
  nested: ClassA;
  classList: Array<ClassA>;  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way you deep copy of the object with `getter & setter` using follwing lodash `clonedeep()` method

```
import * as cloneDeep from 'lodash/cloneDeep';
...
let foo = cloneDeep(bar);
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I would not want to use external libs.

Comment: This library already available in your angular. You don't need installed this one

Comment: I tried it, it works. 
But I not saw when included the lodash into Angular. 
What was the first version which contains it?

Comment: What will happen if we create a project without CLI, the project will contain it? And if we make a production build in that case we should include it into package.json, am I right?

Comment: by default it required to all angular application. without this library your angular project won't work. so no worries you can use it